# authenticate() returns None for User in system when using self.client.post()

Tags: python, django

So I'm currently working on redoing a project I did when I was new to Django. This time I'd like to ensure I'm using tests for practice and getting to know Django better. My issue is that I have a User that I know is in the system, as I have ogged in as them before, but when I run a test using self.client.post(), it returns None. I have triple checked spelling of username and password along with copy-paste the working strings in the func test and still nothing.

Here is the test in question

```
def test_login_authenticates_users(self):
        response = self.client.post('/', {'username' : 'TestUser', 'password' : 'password'})
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/')
        # IDK why this line fails
        self.assertNotEqual(None, authenticate(username='Test.User', password='Usetheforceluke'))
        response = self.client.post('/', {'username' : 'Test.User', 'password' : 'Usetheforceluke'})
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/home')
```

Here is the functional test that works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import unittest

class NewTeacher(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_teacher_adds_a_new_class(self):
        # The MCSP Department has a webpage used for all of the assignments
        # A teacher decides to go to the MSCP homepage to manage their classes

        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')

        # The title mentions MCSP in the title
        self.assertIn('MCSP', self.browser.title)

        # They then log in using their username and password
        username_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('username_input_box')
        password_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('password_input_box')
        self.assertEqual(username_input.get_attribute('placeholder'),
                        'Username')
        self.assertEqual(password_input.get_attribute('placeholder'),
                        'Password')

        # It goes through here to the set failure later in the test
        username_input.send_keys('Test.User')
        password_input.send_keys('Usetheforceluke')
        password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(1)


        # From there they see a navibar that shows "Home", "Grades", "Courses", and "Logout"
        self.assertIn('Home Page', self.browser.title)

        # They are currently on the home page which lets them see upcoming assignments and recent submissions
        self.fail('Finish the test')

        # Next they create a class by using the "Add Course" button on the navbar
        self.fail('Finish the test')

        # They also do so by uploading a spreadsheet
        self.fail('Finish the test')

        # The work done, they log out
        self.fail('Finish the test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I'm trying to keep this down to posting relevant code, i could post the view and the form i have done but as far as i am aware, that shouldn't be affecting this. I have looked into other questions before posting and have added the

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

to my settings.py without change. If anyone needs more code just let me know what!

EDIT: So i did some more messing around by printing all the users in various points and remembered that Djangos TestCase does NOT use the database that the system is on. I forgot that if you want to test authentication, you will need to create the users in the test.

Comment: How did you construct a user?

Comment: added myself as a superuser and added the user through the admin site. Figured I didn't need to code creating users yet

Comment: Hey thanks, solved it